# Convert xlsx or csv date serial numbers to proper date format in Unix server

Tags: unix, date, csv, xlsx

I have converted bunch of .xlsx files into .csv files using xlsx2csv.py,a python module. I have noticed some of the date fields were converted as serial numbers.

```
For example :
41421
41422
41423
41424
41425
```

Can anyone suggest me how to convert these numbers into proper format in Unix server itself using any commands (without taking them to windows desktop and convert it) ?

Comment: What is the original format? And what is the expected format?

Answer (score 0):

its a pure guess,i think you ll have to see the converting scheme used by the python module and then decode it since u have used the python module xlsx2csv.py

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are looking for, but maybe this will point you in the right direction.

Excel date is the number of days since its epoch on January 1, 1900.

Unix date is the number of seconds since its epoch on January 1, 1970.

The arithmetic to convert should be trivial.